# SQL to query historical table that the count of the number of times in the column is 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not even sure what to call this type of query and that's why the title might be misleading. Here's what I want to do. We have a history table that goes like this

```
id, mod_date, is_active
1, 2022-06-22:12:00:00, 1
1, 2022-06-22:13:00:00, 0
2, 2022-06-22:12:00:00, 0
3, 2022-07-07:00:00:00, 1
```

`is_active` means that the record was made active. For example, row `1` was made active at 2022-06-22:12:00:00 and then was made inactive at 13:00:00.

What I want is to get only the row that was made inactive on a specific day and not made active again on that day. I came up with this query

```
select distinct(id)
from history
where is_active = 0
and cast(ah.mod_date as date) = '2022-06-22'
```

It would return 1 and 2. But I only want 2 because 1 was toggled between states. So, I only want to find all of ids that was made inactive on a specific day and never made active again on that day or any of the toggling the same day.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1):

You may phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM history h1
WHERE is_active = 0 AND mod_date::date = '2022-06-22' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM history h2
                  WHERE h2.mod_date::date = '2022-06-22' AND
                        h2.id = h1.id AND h2.is_active = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Count how many times an `id` has been activated and deactivated in a day. From the result select the ones that have been deactivated once and activated zero times.

```sql
with the_historical_table(id, mod_date, is_active) as 
(
 values
  (1, '2022-06-22:12:00:00', 1),
  (1, '2022-06-22:13:00:00', 0),
  (2, '2022-06-22:12:00:00', 0),
  (3, '2022-07-07:00:00:00', 1)
)
select id, mod_date from
(
 select id, mod_date::date, 
    count(*) filter (where is_active = 1) activated,
    count(*) filter (where is_active = 0) deactivated
 from the_historical_table
 group by id, mod_date::date
) t
where activated = 0 and deactivated = 1;
```

Result:

| id | mod_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-06-22 |

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to get only the row that was made inactive on a
> specific day and not made active again on that day

**partition**.: `partition by id, mod_date::date order by id, mod_date`
ordered set **1 0 1**  row **0** the middle row, both lead and lag is **1**. You don't want this situation in the partition.

Consider 3 case.

1. After partition only have one row, is_action = 0 that mean both lead and lag is NULL.
2. Partition have multi rows.
3. Partition have multi rows, ordered set multiple **1** followed by multiple **0**

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=17bb0ea1e6348a9ddb94e0c682b8eccf)

The follow code is like  compute base on these 3 logic and then union all.

---

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        lag(is_active, 1) OVER w,
            lead(is_active, 1) OVER w,
                first_value(is_active) OVER (PARTITION BY id,
                    mod_date::date ORDER BY id,
                    mod_date DESC)
            FROM test1
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id,
    mod_date::date ORDER BY id,
    mod_date)) (
    SELECT
        id,
        mod_date,
        is_active
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE (lead = 0
        OR lead IS NULL)
    AND (lag = 1)
    AND is_active = 0
ORDER BY
    id,
    mod_date)
UNION ALL (
    SELECT
        id,
        mod_date,
        is_active
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        lead IS NULL
        AND lag IS NULL
        AND is_active = 0)
UNION ALL (
    SELECT
        id,
        mod_date,
        is_active
    FROM
        cte
    WHERE
        lead = 0
        AND lag IS NULL
        AND is_active = 0
        AND first_value != 1)
ORDER BY
    id,
    mod_date;
```